# IExecuteCommand keeps launching a new Process/Com Server?

Tags: windows, winapi, com

I'm working on Shell Integration in Windows, using the MS sample below:

https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/main/Samples/Win7Samples/winui/shell/appshellintegration/ExecuteCommandVerb/ExecuteCommandVerb.cpp

The comment on top of this code file reads:

> Note that COM will launch your application if it is not already running and will connect to an already running instance of your application if it is already running.

The sample itself is designed to execute once and then quit - which is working as expected. But, I want my EXE to keep running, so that when the user right-clicks on file(s) in Explorer and selects my verb, the existing instance of my application should be used. I used the code from the sample. However, each time I right-click on a file and select my verb, it's launching a new instance of my EXE (COM server) - which is in contradiction to the comment above.

I tried different `REGCLS` values, but no change in behavior. Also, I tried adding `MultiSelectModel=Player` in the registry (under my verb key), but that didn't help.

Comment: If your COM server is implemented and registered as an out-of-process, single-use server, then indeed COM should only be running 1 instance of it at a time. Are you sure your server is not exiting itself after each time its verb is executed?

Comment: Its not exiting because the UI is being displayed (new window for each invocation). I'm assuming I don't need to have a separate message loop for COM Server and that the main window's message loop on primary thread is sufficient?

Comment: Here's the register call that I'm using:
`classFactory.Register(CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, REGCLS_MULTIPLEUSE);`

Comment: Using `REGCLS_MULTIPLEUSE` is needed, but is not sufficient as the COM server implemented in this sample is a little weird/dumb, I wouldn't use it outside this sample. To demonstrate it works with a multiple use server, just remove the `PostQuitMessage(0)` call in the `if (msg.message == WM_TIMER)` block. It will never quit now and serve all requests, one after the other (so if you let the message box for a first call open, a second one will wait)

Comment: @SimonMourier You're right, after changes, the sample worked as you mentioned. Could it be that my exe is a winrt desktop app which starts with winrt::init_apartment() call, instead of CoInitializeEx() w/STA flag? If so what's a clean of way handling this? because winrt is designed to be multithreaded and it becomes tricky to work with async code in STA mode.

Comment: No this is unrelated, it's just this sample is not a COM server sample, it's an IExecuteCommand sample with a COM server dedicated to this sample. The clean way is to write a COM server sample that supports REGCLS_MULTIPLEUSE.